# Which Destiny should be given to a player who wants to rebuild the Jedi Order?

Tags: character-advancement, star-wars-saga-edition, star-wars

### Introduction

I am currently running my first-ever campaign in Star Wars: Saga Edition: a mildly revised version of the module Dawn of Defiance.

Dawn of Defiance, for those of you who do not know, takes place roughly one year after the end of the Clone Wars, just as the Empire is consolidating power throughout the galaxy.

While Jedi certainly are rare during this era, they do exist and my party has one: a calm, calculating Ithorian. She is dedicated to the Jedi and the Light Side of the Force and has spoken (both in- and out-of-character) about eventually rebuilding the Jedi Order.

Given this, I would like to give her a Destiny that goes well with this goal. Her Destiny will be to (re-)create the Jedi Order and she agrees that it would fit her character spendidly.

### Question

**1.** Which Destiny should I give her to symbolize this quest? Given that she was a part of the Jedi Order before Order 66, there are a few options.

**2.** Depending on ***1***, what would be suitable as 24 hour rewards and penalties while advancing towards her Destiny?

*I realize that this question may seem opinion-based, but I'm looking for answers based on reasoning and, if possible, references to Star Wars material both inside and outside of the Star Wars: Saga Edition system.*

Comment: Given the period, I'm guessing her destiny will be to die at the hands of Darth Vader, but sure, one can dream :P

Comment: Answers on matters of creative taste, even when based on reasoning and built on top of setting knowledge, are still primarily opinion-based.